# PHP MySQL How to query specific value from column

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL`-table wih the columns

- order_item_id
- meta_key
- meta_value

inside the column `meta_key` there are "keys" like price, id and quantity

now I want to query the quantity for all my orders but I don't really know how to get the quantity key.

```
SELECT im.order_item_id, i.order_item_name, i.order_id 
FROM `order_itemmeta` im  
    RIGHT JOIN `order_items` i ON im.order_item_id = i.order_item_id 
WHERE im.meta_value = "' . $todays_date . '"');
```

I tried to do something like `im.meta_key = '_qty'` but it doesn't work obviously.

So can someone help me out?

Comment: `WHERE \`im.meta_key\` LIKE '%_qty%'` might work. Give us a SQLFiddle.com fiddle, I'll be able to help you quick. `:)` And you gotta use the aggregate functions.

Comment: Yea, @Devon agree with you. Anyway, I have requested for SQLFiddle.... Let's see.

Comment: It would help if you incuded ALL of that function call as without it that string looks like somthig is missing

Comment: Seems like just a bad design.  Why would you store the date in a meta value of an order item instead of just on the order itself?

Comment: But do you mean something as simple as `WHERE im.meta_value = '$todays_date' AND im.meta_key = '_qty' ");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to aggregate a different meta_key/value combination of the same order_item_id's:

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM `order_itemmeta` im2 
WHERE meta_key = '_qty' AND 
im2.order_item_id IN (
  SELECT im.order_item_id
  FROM `order_itemmeta` im  
  RIGHT JOIN `order_items` i ON im.order_item_id = i.order_item_id 
  WHERE im.meta_value = "' . $todays_date . '"
);
```